# Is there a problem in creating a fileobject inside a function, returning it to the parent function, and closing it there?

Tags: python

consider the python code below:

```py
    def create_fout_bt(location):
        fout = open(os.path.join(location, 'The Book Thief.txt'), 'w')
# Added 'w' in Edit 1. Can't believe none of you guys noticed it! :P
        return fout
    
    def main():
        location = r'E:\Books\Fiction'
        fout_bt = create_fout_bt(location)
        fout_bt.write('Author: Markus Zusak\n')
        fout_bt.close()
    
    main()
```

In this code, the fileobject named fout is created inside the function create_fout_bt, but not closed within the same function. What I understand is that we have to close every fileobject we create; so is this ok? In practice, the code works fine and the output file is generated with the content I wrote to it, but just wondering if a fileobject is dangling somewhere out there.

Thanks for your time.

### Edit 1:

Thank you for introducing me to the python with statement. Hopefully I'll use it in the future.

Also, let me clarify that the code I mentioned here is a generic, simple case. Of course it doesn't make sense to define a function just to create a fileobject! In the real scenario, I will be writing to many different files concurrently. For example:

```py
fout1.write('%s: %f' %('Magnetic Field', magnetic_field))
fout2.write('%s: %f' %('Power', power))
fout3.write('%s: %f' %('Cadence', cadence))
```

Now this requires creating the fileobjects fout1, fout2, fout3:

```py
fout1 = open(os.path.join(rootPath, 'filename1.txt'), 'w')
fout2 = open(os.path.join(rootPath, 'filename2.txt'), 'w')
fout3 = open(os.path.join(rootPath, 'filename3.txt'), 'w')
```

Since there are many of them, I wanted to put them inside a function to make it look better - now a single function call will get me all the fileobjects:

```py
fout1, fout2, fout3 = create_file_objects(rootPath)
```

Moreover, in the real scenario, I have to write into a file at multiple locations in the program. From what I have understood, if I'm using 'with', I'll have to open the file in append mode each time I have to write into it (making the code look cluttered); compared to using an 'open()' function which will keep the file open till I use the close() function.

Like [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) commented, the problem I'm worried about is spreading the responsibility of the fileobject to multiple functions. In my first example,
'fout' is the variable created inside the function 'create_fout_bt' and 'fout_bt' is the variable to which that value is assigned by the latter. Now, I know 'fout_bt' is taken care of with the statement 'fout_bt.close()', but what about 'fout' inside the function 'create_fout_bt'? Will it be disposed off when the function 'create_fout_bt' returns?

Hope my doubt is more clear. Do let me know if I just missed something obvious. Any comments on how to make my future posts more palatable will also be much appreciated. :)

Comment: No, If you want, you can try writing to a file: ```fout_bt.write("Test if file is closed")``` after ```fout_bt.close()```. If it raises and error, then the file is closed successfully. If it writes, then the file is open

Comment: @Sujay I try it, it raises an error `I/O operation on closed file`.

Comment: That means the file is closed.

Comment: Note that this is unnecessary complication of the code and also it's better to use `with` context manager.

Answer (score 1):

- Your code works fine, I try @Sujay 's suggestion, it raises an error `I/O operation on closed file` after `fout_bt.close()`
- If you afraid of your code style, you can use `with` to do it.

#### code:

```
def create_fout_bt(location):
    fout = open(os.path.join(location, 'The Book Thief.txt'),"a")
    return fout

def main():
    location = r'E:\Books\Fiction'
    with create_fout_bt(location) as fout_bt:
        fout_bt.write('Author: Markus Zusak\n')

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing is that the code that opens the file (`create_fout_bt`) cannot guarantee that the file will also be closed. Which isn't an issue per se, but it spreads that responsibility around and *may* lead to situations in which the file isn't closed, because the caller doesn't handle the returned file handle correctly. It's still fine to do this, you just need to be diligent. One way this could be improved is with this:

```
with create_fout_bt(location) as fout_bt:
    fout_bt.write('Author: Markus Zusak\n')
```

Using a `with` context manager on the file object, regardless of whether directly created with `open` or "indirectly" via `create_fout_bt`, guarantees that the file will be closed, regardless of errors happening in your code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'with'.

with 'with' you don't need to close your files anymore and it automatically close it self.

do it like this :

```
with create_fout_bt(location) as fout_bt:
    fout_bt.write('Author: Markus Zusak\n')
```